# Why does iOS stop playing after 16 videos and then give a black display on html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a site where there are a ton of videos of mp4 to show. After you play 16 videos in a row just fine, the next videos presents the video div with the play button with a line through it. The problem only occurs in the iOS version. The Android version has no issues playing more than 16 videos.

Below is some very simple code so you can understand that the problem does not come from my code. And if you could tell me how to solve the problem via html, js or php.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var myVideos = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    myVideos += "<video controls muted loop playsinline width='400' src='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4'></video><br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myVideos;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is what my iphone shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtFhD.png)

Answer (score 1):

*I already answered this in your other posts, but placing this here just in case those others are deleted as this is the original.*

This happens as a result of hardware constraints on Mobile devices. You need to clear the Video's resources after playback has finished.

Something like this should work.

```
var video = document.getElementById('videoID');
var child = null;

while(child = video.firstChild) {
    if(child.nodeName === 'SOURCE') {
       child.src = '';
   }

   video.removeChild(child);
}

video.load();
```

View this Site for more info..
https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, my apologies I had not seen your answer the first time. That said, I still do not understand how to put your piece of code with mine.

Comment: Can you please be more specific ?